# $this->view->headStyle()->captureStart() does not work in View Helper

Tags: css, zend-framework

This is my code:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Fonts extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function fonts()
    {
        $this->view->headStyle()->captureStart();?>
        p {color: blue}
        <?php $this->view->headStyle()->captureEnd();
    }
}
```

But there is no such style when I check it in the browser.
This view helper is run in Controller like this:

```
$this->view->fonts();
```

It is working (I checked it with echo and exit) but there is no trace of this style. It should add

```
p {color: blue}
```

style to header, should not?

Comment: Are you calling `$this->headStyle()` in your layout?

Comment: Now I do and it works, thank you.